# How to convert Visual Studio ‘s sln file to cmake or makefile?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, makefile, fortran, intel-oneapi

On Windows, with Intel OneAPI (mostly Fortran) and Visual Studio.
Does anyone know how to convert Visual Studio 's sln file(the solution file) to cmake or Makefile?

I tried cmake-converter,
https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter

however, it seems by default cannot catch compile flags such as

/QxHost

/heap-arrays0

and some linking flags such as

/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE

/STACK:2147483647,2147483647

/LARGEADDRESSAWARE

I mean I can write Makefile on Windows from my Visual Studio 's solution, but is there an automatic tool which can simply convert the sln file to a cmake file or makefile?

Comment: Much, MUCH better to just write it from scratch. There are no widely used automatic converter tools.

Comment: It's not the .sln file you want to convert, but the .vfproj project file. The Solution (.sln) file just contains pointers to the projects. Visual Studio used to have a tool to write a makefile, but Microsoft dropped it years ago. What I usually do is copy the set of commands listed in the buildlog.htm and turn that into a batch file.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much Dr. Fortran @SteveLionel ! Thank you Alex too!